# Select CheckBoxes in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel sheet having check boxes from Range "D12" to "D26", on  click of abutton I want to select all checkboxes but based on only range i.e. all checkboxes in `Range("D12:D26")`.

Code which I am using is below, but not working for me:

```
Private Sub SelectALL_Click()

    Dim cells As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("D12:D14")



    For Each cells In rng
        cells.Select
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: What type of checkbox are they - Forms or ActiveX ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have not mentioned what kind of control is it (ActiveX or Form Control), take your pick

**Form Control Example**

```
Sub FormControl_Example()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim rng As Range, rngShp As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<~~ Change this to the relevant sheet name
        Set rng = .Range("D12:D14")

        For Each shp In .Shapes
            Set rngShp = .Range(shp.TopLeftCell.Address)

            If Not Intersect(rngShp, rng) Is Nothing Then
                shp.OLEFormat.Object.Value = True
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

**ActiveX Control Example**

```
Sub ActiveX_Example()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim rng As Range, rngShp As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<~~ Change this to the relevant sheetname
        Set rng = .Range("D12:D14")

        For Each shp In .Shapes
            Set rngShp = .Range(shp.TopLeftCell.Address)

            If Not Intersect(rngShp, rng) Is Nothing Then
                .OLEObjects(shp.Name).Object.Value = True
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```